# Why should we sometimes place the subject between auxiliary and P.P. in present perfect?

Tags: grammar

I saw an English grammar test in an official exam which made me confused.
Here is the test:

> "Only in the past hundred years, though, **[...]** systematic objective techniques that have enabled us to study our recollections of the past with scientific accuracy and reproducibility.
>
> 1. [psychologists have developed]
> 2. [have psychologists developed]

Interestingly the answer was (2).

Now my question is about the grammatical structure of this sentence. Is the answer true, and if yes, why should we put the subject between have and P.P..

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: so suggest something better, it simply came to my mind that it might relate to the adverbial role of "though".

Comment: @the-baby-is-you How does the subject not relate to the question? Reza is clearly asking why the subject (psychologists) is placed between the auxiliary (have) and the PP (developed). I'm a little confused as to why the title doesn't make sense!

Comment: @Bee I changed the title after its comment, the previous was: though as an adverb

Comment: Ah sorry it didn't say you'd edited when I commented, very weird!